# Can I purchase an SSL certificate from one hosting vendor, but use it on another?

Tags: dns, https

In Jul-2016, I purchased a domain name and hosting from Vendor A and in Nov-2016, I purchased an ecommerce solution from Vendor B.

Vendor B asked me to inform Vendor A to point my domain to their DNS/A record i.e. dns.vendorb.com.

My question is, can I still purchase and install an SSL certificate from Vendor A and have my site show HTTPS even though it is pointing to Vendor B?

I've been given conflicting answers regarding this. Really appreciate if someone could clarify. Thanks!

Comment: With letsencrypt out there offering free SSL, why would you purchase an SSL certificate at all?

Comment: Really? Thanks for the heads up. Will explore it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an ssl from either your hosting provider, your domain registrar or a different company entirely and it works either way.